# Serialize/Deserialize nested objects in flat structure

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm sure that somewhere there is a simple answer to my question, but I couldn't fin it. The problem I faced is following, I have code structure:

```
class Field
{   
    List<Block> Blocks {get;set;}

    public static Field CreateField()
    {
        var A = new Block {Connector = new Connector()}
        var B = new Block {Connector = new Connector()}

        A.Connector.ConnectedTo.Add(B);
        B.Connector.ConnectedTo.Add(A);

        var field = new Field();
        field.Blocks = new List {A, B};

        return field;
    }
}

class Block
{
    Connector Connector {get;set;}
}

class Connector
{
    List<Block> ConnectedTo {get;set;}
}
```

Than serialization command using json.net:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Field.CreateField(), Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings {PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects});
```

and output result is as expected:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Blocks": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Connector": {
                "$id": "3",
                "ConnectedTo": [
                    {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "Connector":{
                            "$id": "5",
                            "ConnectedTo": [
                                {
                                    "$ref": "2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to have serialization result as following:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Blocks": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Connector": {
                "$id": "3",
                "ConnectedTo": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "4"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$id": "4",
            "Connector":{
                "$id": "5",
                "ConnectedTo": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it flattened? Take a look at how you can serialize data with circular references here: http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/

Comment: Kvam, thanks for the repsponse. At first I need it to be human friendly  (user should be able open json file and modify it), right now it's almost impossible where and how it goes from. Then output file with 10-20 blocks looks almost impossible to modify using json path, especially when we need to replace something to something (version upgrade process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  In your second example, `$ref : 4` points to an `$id` that occurs *later* in the JSON.  Json.Net will not be able to deserialize this-- when it comes upon a `$ref` it expects to be able to resolve it to an `$id` that it has already seen.

I would recommend against requiring users modify JSON directly anyway unless they are technically savvy.  As I've seen from answering many JSON-related questions on SO, it is very easy to get the format messed up if you edit it manually-- missing quotes or commas, mismatched braces, invalid syntax, you name it.  What will you do when someone screws it up?  I think a better option is to make a tool that allows manipulating your structure abstractly.  The tool could deserialize the original JSON, allow certain changes and then reserialize it into the new structure.  Users would not need to know anything about the underlying JSON format that way.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I thought.

Comment: I agree that allowing user to modify json file is not a good idea, but that's what customer would like to have and we still arguing about. The problem with the tool (or whatever) is following: we will have to keep all original models to deserialize json files correctly and when we upgraded our assets from v1 to v3 it's very easy to imagine how many trash we will have to keep. Another idea is to work with dynamic structures, but i'm not sure how easy or difficult it would be,